# How to get the predictation result in csv format from shared variables

Tags: theano

Data is shared variables. I want to get the predictation result in csv format. Below is the code. 
It throws an error. How to fix?  Thank you for your help!

```
TypeError: ('Bad input argument to theano function with name "4.py:305"  at index 
0(0-based)', 'Expected an array-like object, 
but found a Variable: maybe you are trying to call a function on a (possibly shared)  
variable instead of a numeric array?')

test_model = theano.function(
    inputs=[index],
    outputs=classifier.errors(y),
    givens={
        x: test_set_x[index * batch_size:(index + 1) * batch_size],
        y: test_set_y[index * batch_size:(index + 1) * batch_size]
    }
)

def make_submission_csv(predict, is_list=False):
    if is_list:
        df = pd.DataFrame({'Id': range(1, 101), 'Label': predict})
        df.to_csv("submit.csv", index=False)
        return
    pred = []
    for i in range(100):
        pred.append(test_model(test.values[i]))
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Id': range(1, 101), 'Label': pred})
    df.to_csv("submit.csv", index=False)
make_submission_csv(np.argmax(test_model(test_set_x), axis=1), is_list=True)
```

And more information about "index".

```
index = T.iscalar()  
x = T.matrix('x')  
y = T.ivector('y')
```

when enter:

```
test_set_x.get_value(borrow=True)
```

The console shows:

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       ..., 
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]], dtype=float32)
```

When enter:

```
test_model(test_set_x.get_value())
```

It throws an error:

```
TypeError: ('Bad input argument to theano function with name "4.py:311"  at index 0(0-based)', 'TensorType(int32, scalar) cannot store a value of dtype float32 without risking loss of precision.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `test_model` function has a single input value,

```
inputs=[index],
```

Your pasted code doesn't show the creation of the variable `index` but my guess is that it's a Theano symbolic scalar with an integer type. If so, you need to call the compiled function with a single integer input, for example

```
test_model(1)
```

You are trying to call `test_model(test_set_x)` which doesn't work because `test_set_x` is (again probably) a shared variable, not the integer index the function is expecting.

Note that the [tutorial code](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/code/logistic_sgd.py) does this:

```
test_losses = [test_model(i) for i in xrange(n_test_batches)]
```

Comment: Thanks, Daniel.

Here is my code:

    index = T.iscalar()  
    x = T.matrix('x')  
    y = T.ivector('y')

Comment: Okay. So I was right about `index` but still unclear about `test_set_x` (though I assume you're using the code from the Theano tutorial, e.g. http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/code/logistic_sgd.py where `test_set_x` equals `theano.shared(numpy.asarray(data_x, dtype=theano.config.floatX), borrow=borrow)`. Does your problem remain?

Comment: I use kaggle-digits csv data for testing:

    test_set_x = theano.shared(np.array(test.values[:][:, 1:], dtype=np.float32)/256)
    test_set_y = theano.shared(np.array(test.values[:][:, 0], dtype=int))

Comment: Okay, so my guess was correct about that too. Does your problem remain?

Comment: still cannot get the predication result.

Comment: Then I suspect you're still using the `test_model` function incorrectly. You shouldn't pass the shared variable as an input. Instead you should identify which batch to use for the test, or loop over many batches. See updated answer.

Comment: test_losses is a short list. Could you explain what it means? The size of test_set_x  is 100*785. How can we get the predication list for test_set_x?
    `In[16]:test_losses`
    `Out[16]: [array(0.05), array(0.2), array(0.15), array(0.1), array(0.1)]`

Comment: `test_losses` will have length equal to `n_test_batches`, i.e. the number of batches in the test set (roughly the test set size divided by the batch size). If you're using the tutorial code then the contents will be loss values, not predictions. If you want predictions then you'll need to modify the `test_model` function, or create a new function. If you don't know how to do that then I suggest you need to learn a bit more about Theano before continuing, please work through the tutorials in more detail.